# HTML 5 drag and drop

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

i want to make a sidebar with some menu and the menu should can drag and drop !

here is the code :

```
                <div class="sidebar"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                <div class="about" draggable="true"  ondragstart="drag(event)" id="about">
                    <div class="top"><p>about us</p></div>
                    <p class="about"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="contact" draggable="true"  ondragstart="drag(event)" id="contact">
                    <div class="top"><p>contact us</p></div>
                    <form class="contact" action="script/mail.php" method="post" target="ifrm">
                     //Some INPUT
                    </form>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

the drag and drop is working well now but it's also pussible to drag "about us" and contact us" into eachother or into the form input and  i want to disable this !!!
how i sould do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Learn about [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/8655), then check `event.target` in your `drop()` and `allowDrop()` functions.